# variable as template parameter input

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to use variables set true or false as a string and passing it into template using the below code in the azure build pipeline.

```
  jobs:
  - job: run
    condition: eq(variables.runstage, true)
    timeoutInMinutes: 500
    steps:
      - template: './process.yaml'
        parameters:
          mail_trigger: $(enabled)
```

In my process.yaml file

```
parameters:
- name: enabled
  type: string
```

My task using the parameter

```
- ${{ if eq(parameters.enabled, true) }}:
  - task: some task
```

But the tasks are being skipped even after giving true as value for enabled variable.

Please help

Comment: try use the same case instead of True and true

Comment: I have passed true and the condition is checking is it true. My problem is the task is getting skipped even setting value as true @crowne

Comment: Your parameter is defined as a string. true as a string becomes "true" with quotes. Why not define it as a boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I did it to conditionally run my tests. The job using this template can choose if it needs to run tests or not.

**In your template**

First declare your RunTests under parameters as a boolean

```
parameters:
- name: RunTests
  type: boolean
  default: true
```

In your task use the condition parameter to check the boolean value. I don't think you need the eq operator.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: '.NET Test'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ${{parameters.RunTests}} )
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: ${{ parameters.testProjectFilePath }}
    arguments: '--configuration release --no-restore --collect "Code coverage" --logger trx --results-directory "$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResults'
    publishTestResults: false
```

**In the task using this template**

You can pass in the RunTests parameter.

```
- template: templates/yourtemplate.yml
  parameters:
    RunTests: ${{eq(parameters['RunTests'], 'yes')}}
```

Edit: I'm checking against "yes" because I'm showing a prompt to the user with a yes or no radio when the job is run. (as seen [here](https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/azure-devops-pipelines-prompt-a-question-to-the-user-f2af1199f431)). But you should be able to pass in a boolean value just as well.